# Where do I start at this site?

Tags: discussion

I am really interested in puzzle solving especially if it is relating to mathematics or logic or similar. But, I look at the level of questions asked here and do not know how to begin to solve any. They all seem too time-consuming, complex and difficult. I want to solve the easy ones and keep progressing and improving my skills.

But, where do I start? Are there any less complex puzzles that I can begin with? Can anybody please guide me as to where I should start from?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the puzzles posted here are hard. Others are difficult. There's really no way to easily tell what a puzzle's difficulty level will be - and sometimes the writer of the puzzle will misjudge the level of difficulty as well.

You can sometimes tell by who posted it - generally, puzzles that I post will be on the easier side, while puzzles by [Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja) will often be amazingly difficult.

If you want to try your hand at something, you can always look at whatever new puzzles pop up and take a look at them. Some will be hard. Some will be easy. Some will be awful, and some will be astounding. But there's really no easy way to tell what will be what, for easy finding.

---

If you want to find specifically [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) and [logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction) puzzles, you can follow a tag (see [How do I follow a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121207/294691) on Meta.SE), as well as add the tags as favorites on the right sidebar on the main page to make these puzzles appear with a highlight on question pages.

Answer (score 0):

Having posted a lot of puzzles, my experience on PSE is that many solvers are amazingly talented and fast. My "simple" puzzles were answered in few minutes and "hard" ones in hours. So I tend to design only what I consider as hard puzzles only. I suspect many other OPs also do the same. That could be a criterion to decide which puzzles are easy (ones solved in no time!)